# Count number of record by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code helps me to show the most recent previous attendance. Essential, it shows the last time they attended - not today's attendance. It's working well, however I want to add a count column to show how many times they have attended so far.

```
select top ID, IDATE
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by IDATE desc ) as 'rowNum', ID, IDATE
    from ATTENDANCE A 
    INNER JOIN STUDENT_LINE SL ON A.ID = SL.ID 
    ) withRowNum 
   where rowNum = 2
```

What I'm looking to is something like this:

```
ID | DATE | Count
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: The `top` in the `select` should return a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count in the subquery:

```
select ID, IDATE, cnt
from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by IDATE desc) as rowNum,
             ID, IDATE,
             COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as cnt
     from ATTENDANCE A join
          STUDENT_LINE SL
          ON A.ID = SL.ID 
    ) asl 
where rowNum = 2
```